# OpenCV 2.4.8: module compiled against API version 9

Tags: opencv, python-2.7, numpy

I just installed the opencv 2.4.8 . I'm using python 2.7. I tried to add the opencv lib to  python according to this [tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_setup/py_setup_in_windows/py_setup_in_windows.html). but when I tried to import the opencv I got this error:

```
import cv2
   RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 9 but this version 
   of numpy is 7

   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
   import cv2
   ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
```

I *updated* my scipy and numpy packages to its *latest version*, but I got the same error. How to fix this problem? I googled it but I found some solutions for Mac OS.

I use Windows 7.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I got this error too. Finally I figure out I should update numpy to the latest version.

The version of numpy in the tutorial is version 7, but now the team is using version 9 (but numpy team name it 1.8 publicly).

For convenience, check [here](https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/numpy/NumPy/1.8.0/numpy-1.8.0-win32-superpack-python2.7.exe) to download the version I use.

To download the latest version, check [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/latest/download).

Comment: I updated the numpy and SciPy but the problem didn't solved :).

Comment: It is strange. The update solved my problem, but I encounter link error when compiling the source code. BTW, my platform is windows 7.

Comment: Worked for me. I was following this tutorial : http://opencvpython.blogspot.fr/2012/05/install-opencv-in-windows-for-python.html  but updated with the numpy version lesca used

Comment: Appears as version 0x9 in error message but is named 1.8 publicly.... ugh ugh ugh they need to do things that make sense.

Answer (score 4):

I build OpenCV from source and the problem solved. I used [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/resources/software.html) to do that.Don't forget to change the path to the new bin directory in your environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

If you want you can get the 1.9.1 superpack from the following URL.

[numpy-1.9.1-win32-superpack-python2.7](https://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/NumPy/1.9.1/numpy-1.9.1-win32-superpack-python2.7.exe/download?use_mirror=kent&r=https%3A%2F%2Fsourceforge.net%2Fprojects%2Fnumpy%2Ffiles%2FNumPy%2F1.9.1%2F&use_mirror=kent)

This resolved my issue likady split. :)