# Runtime error with module Pandas

Tags: python, numpy, import

after messing around a bit I now have this error when importing `pandas`: `RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 9 but this version of numpy is 6` (details below). On a long term, this should be solved using `virtualenv`. On a short term, do you know how should I fix this?

`>>> import pandas
RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 9 but this version of numpy is 6`

Answer (score 1):

What version python? Rebuild/reinstall numpy?

```
pip uninstall numpy; pip install numpy
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21647753/1821490

Comment: I ended up installing Anaconda, so now I have some new problem (cv2 does not load). Thanks by the way!