# Install Opencv for Python on Windows

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, installation

I try to install opencv for python. I use windows x64. I install `numpy1.6` and `python2.7`. I have installed `opencv2.4.9`. I install them succesfully. I guide from [this page](http://opencvpython.blogspot.com.tr/2012/05/install-opencv-in-windows-for-python.html). It says that

> Now open your "Python IDLE" ( from Start > All Programs > Python 2.7 > Python IDLE ) and just type following :
>   import cv2

When I run `import cv2`, I get below error :

```
module compiled against API version 9 but this version of numpy is 6.
```

How can I know compatible version?

I know this question [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20999939/opencv-2-4-8-module-compiled-against-api-version-9). But I installed latest numpy version, it didn't solve my problem.

Comment: I don't agree with the advice on the duplicate question. Install the Anaconda distribution.

Answer (score 2):

Use https://www.scivision.co/install-opencv-3-0-x-for-python-on-windows/
It's going to lead you to http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#opencv where you can download a .whl installer. After you download it, you can run it using 
    pip install some-file.whl
assuming you have pip installed. After that you should be able to import cv2.

I had the same problem and I did a ton of research but this is the only one that worked.

Comment: this solution worked for me, but needed to rename ton win 32, although I use Windows 64 and python is installed correctly. It was the same for numpy.