# Installing python-cv from

Tags: python, opencv, installation

I am following the installation process stated [here](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d5/de5/tutorial_py_setup_in_windows.html#gsc.tab=0). I am stuck on step 7; I get an ImportError stating:

```
"RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 9 but this version of numpy is 7
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>

import cv2
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import"
```

In the instructions it recommends me to install the latest version of opencv, so as trial and error i tried an earlier model to see what would happen...i get the same thing -_-.

Could anyone point to me what I'm doing wrong, if there are no feasible solutions, is there a more stable process of doing this

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Someone experienced a similar error [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20999939/opencv-2-4-8-module-compiled-against-api-version-9).  Make sure your numpy is up to date and don't forget to change the path to the new bin directory in your environment variable.

Comment: Thanks for the referral, I've found the solution.  It was to do with the numpy version i was using :).

Comment: Awsome awesome!  Glad to hear you were able to take care of it!  =)