# Error when importing OpenCV 2.4.11 in Python 2.7

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

Whenever I try to import OpenCV in python 2.7 it gives me the error:

```
import cv2
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application (When using
```

the x64 version), and when I use the x86 version I get

```
import cv2
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
```

also, when I try to import numpy.core.multiarray, it says:

```
the API was compiled against numpy version 9 but you have version 7
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'core'
```

I am using Windows 10 & OpenCV 2.4.11 (I tried opencv 3.0.0 but it gives the same error) & I used this guide to install opencv http://opencvpython.blogspot.co.uk/2012/05/install-opencv-in-windows-for-python.html

Comment: The error-message is very clear: you have an outdated numpy version.

Comment: I don't know how to update it though... I have tried going on to sourceforge and getting the latest installer and then using that, but it still gives the same error. Also `pip install numpy --upgrade` does nothing. Thanks for helping @deets

Comment: I am using Numpy 1.6.1 as returned by `numpy.__version__` @deets

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20999939/opencv-2-4-8-module-compiled-against-api-version-9 - you need Numpy 1.8

Comment: Thanks so much! It worked! Maybe you'll want to write an answer so I can mark it as accepted. You'll probably get some reputation as well @deets

Answer (score 0):

If anything doesn't work, what the main cause can be is that you should download the 32-bit version of OpenCV (3.x) and Python (2.x) because [NumPy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NumPy) is not available in a 64-bit version as of now (2016-07-06). You can visit *[Install OpenCV-Python in Windows](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_setup/py_setup_in_windows/py_setup_in_windows.html)* (for Windows; for another OS reach the page a step behind).