# How can I stop numpy_1.8 from masking numpy_1.10?

Tags: python, numpy, pythonpath, sys.path

I had thought I was using the most recent version of numpy (1.10) At least, when I run `pip list` I see `numpy (1.10.4)`. However, when I get into the python interpreter and type

```
import numpy
numpy.__version__
```

I see

```
'1.8.2'
```

I expect that the 1.8.2 got installed sometime after the 1.10 version, because I've recently installed some new packages and I now when I run some code that used to work, I get this error:

```
RuntimeError: module compiled against API version a but this version of numpy is 9
```

In [OpenCV 2.4.8: module compiled against API version 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20999939/opencv-2-4-8-module-compiled-against-api-version-9) the accepted answer mentioned that the numpy team refers to version 1.8 as numpy version 9. So, I think that I was originally using numpy_1.10, and somehow got numpy_1.8 installed.

My first question is How did this happen and how can I guard against it?

I also want to know how I can stop numpy_1.8 from blocking 1.10. My initial  thought was to remove numpy_1.8 using apt-get, but that would've removed many other packages that are dependent upon 1.8.

I'd be tempted to just use rm to get rid of the 1.8 version, but am worried that those other packages would be affected.

My second thought is to change sys.path to make certain the 1.10 version is seen before the 1.8 version. So far, I'm not using PYTHONPATH. Is there a way to change sys.path without using PYTHONPATH? Is this a reasonable approach to take?

Comment: OK - I suppose using virtualenv, or Docker would help me, but I still need to figure out what to do now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest thing to do is to remove your NumPy 1.8 installation. Look at `numpy.__file__` to find where your 1.8 installation is, then delete the directory.

Alternatively, as you mentioned and if you don't want to delete 1.8, you could also change your path. Something like this ought to do it:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(3, '<path_to_your_NumPy_1.10_install>')
```

I've inserted at position 3 so that you keep things like `''` at the top, but you could modify this as needed.

Comment: Thanks, but from what I can tell, this only works for a single invocation of the python interpreter. I don't want to need to remember this any time I load a module that needs numpy_1.10

Comment: @user1245262; what's your objection to the first half of this solution?

Comment: When I tried to remove numpy_1.8 using synaptic, it listed several other packages that rely upon numpy_1.8 which would be deleted. If I just use rm -rf to remove the directory where numpy_1.8 lives, what happens to the packages that depend upon it? Will the find numpy_1.10 on their own or will I set off a cascade of packages that need to be removed & reinstalled?

Comment: I prefer managing my Python software with pip rather than an OS tool for exactly these reasons. How many packages are in the cascade?

Comment: I can't tell right now, but as I recall it's about 10-20.

Comment: I ended up using synaptic to remove numpy and reinstall all the packages that depended upon it. I figured since I was best off using pip to manage all my Python packages, I'd be reinstalling the extra packages anyway.